# How to get mouse/touch events reactively in angular 9+?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I've been looking for a library or best practice for handling common user events reactively and have had no luck.

I found a decent solution: https://github.com/trxcllnt/rxjs-gestures
But I wasn't able to get it imported into my angular project.

I want to listen in on mouse and touch drag events, as well as clicks, taps, swipes and long presses.

Has anyone found any good solutions within angular?

Answer (score 0):

**Ionic Framework** has already an utility for gestures. You need Ionic version 5 or greater to use them. You can see the full documentation about the gestures [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures#:%7E:text=Ionic%20Gestures%20is%20a%20utility,be%20building%20an%20Ionic%20app!). Hope this helps you!. Happy Coding :)